# Deferencing a pointer to a pointer causes a segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers

Why is that the fourth line has an error?

```
   char** h_addr_list = "Hello world";
   char* s = "Hello world";
   printf("%s\n", s);
   printf("%s\n", *h_addr_list);   // segmentation fault
```

Comment: That's because the first line of code is not valid. It's declared as a `char **` but that's not what you are assigning to it.

Comment: Compile with `-Wall` or equivalent. You have a type mismatch.

Comment: If you don't get an error message for this code then adjust your compiler settings, you are just wasting time by trying to run erroneous code

Answer (score 0):

Because when %s qualifier is given, printf function expects a pointer to NULL terminated character-string to be passed as the argument.

The h_addr_list itself is a pointer to NULL terminated character string.
The *h_addr_list is not.

So, these would work,

```
printf("%s\n", h_addr_list); 
printf("%c\n", *h_addr_list);
```